# Why won't records delete?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I wrote a plugin that gets the GUID IDs through fetchXML and uses Batch delete to delete the records in batches of 1000.

I debugged the plugin and it shows that the plugin executes all the way through to `service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchxml))`, however, the fetched records are not getting deleted. Can someone explain why? Here is the plugin code:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;


/// <summary>
/// This plugin will trimm off unit orders after a contract is cancelled before the end of the contract duration
/// </summary>

namespace DCWIMS.Plugins
{

    [CrmPluginRegistration(MessageNameEnum.Update,
    "contract",
    StageEnum.PostOperation,
    ExecutionModeEnum.Asynchronous,
    "statecode",
    "Post-Update On Cancel Contract",
    1000,
    IsolationModeEnum.Sandbox,
    Image1Name = "PreImage",
    Image1Type = ImageTypeEnum.PreImage,
    Image1Attributes = "")]

    public class UnitPluginOnCancel : IPlugin
    {

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
            // Will be registering this plugin, thus will need to add tracing service related code.

            ITracingService tracing = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            //obtain execution context from service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // Output Parameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request. 

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {

                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                //Get the before image of the updated contract
                Entity PreImage = context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];


                //verify that target entity is contract and contains a cancellation date
                if (entity.LogicalName != "contract" || entity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value != 4)
                    return;

                if (PreImage.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 0 || entity.Contains("cancelon"))
                    return;

                if (PreImage.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 3 || PreImage.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 1)
                    return;

                //obtain the organization service for web service calls.
                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                    (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);


                //Core Plugin code in Try Block
                try
                {

                    //Get Contract line start date
                    var startDate = PreImage.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("cancelon");

                    //Get Contract Line End Date
                    DateTime endDate = (DateTime)PreImage["expireson"];

                    //Get Contract range into weekdays list
                    Eachday range = new Eachday();
                    var weekdays = range.WeekDay(startDate, endDate);

                    //Get Unit Order Lookup Id
                    EntityReference unitOrder = (EntityReference)PreImage.Attributes["new_unitorderid"];

                    var unitOrders = service.Retrieve(unitOrder.LogicalName, unitOrder.Id, new ColumnSet("new_name"));
                    var unitOrdersId = unitOrders.Id;

                    var uiName = unitOrders.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_name");

                    //Get Entity Collection to delete 

                    string fetchXml = @" <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false' top='2000'>
                        <entity name='new_units'>
                            <link-entity name='new_alterunitorder' from ='new_orderlineid' to = 'new_unitsid' >
                                <attribute name='new_alterunitorderid' />
                                <filter type='and'>
                                    <condition attribute='new_orderdate' operator='on-or-after' value='" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_orderdate' operator='on-or-before' value='" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_orderlineid' operator='eq' uiname='" + uiName + @"' uitype='new_units' value='" + unitOrdersId + @"' />
                                </filter>
                            </link-entity>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch>";


                    var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));

                    var entityRefs = result.Entities.Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_alterunitorderid"));


                    var batchSize = 1000;
                    var batchNum = 0;
                    var numDeleted = 0;

                    while (numDeleted < entityRefs.Count())
                    {
                        var multiReq = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
                        {
                            Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                            {
                                ContinueOnError = false,
                                ReturnResponses = false
                            },
                            Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
                        };

                        var currentList = entityRefs.Skip(batchSize * batchNum).Take(batchSize).ToList();

                        currentList.ForEach(r => multiReq.Requests.Add(new DeleteRequest { Target = r }));

                        service.Execute(multiReq);

                        numDeleted += currentList.Count;
                        batchNum++;
                    }


                }
                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured.. Phil is responsible. ", ex);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracing.Trace("An error occured: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }


        }

    }

}
```

I tried this:

```C#
var entityGuids = result.Entities.Select(ent => ent.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_alterunitorderid"));
var entityRefs = entityGuids.Select(guid => new EntityReference("new_alterunitorder", guid));
```

Got this:

[image: guids are not being retrieved]

Comment: Phil is never responsible

Comment: Since you seem to be encountering a lot of challenges with debugging, you may want to build this first as a Console App, then after debugging, switch to a plugin. I typically put all my business logic into a Visual Studio Shared Project. Then I build and debug via console app, before registering as a plugin.

Comment: sound advice!! I will get on that. Thank you!

Comment: One point of advice: `ExecuteMultipleRequest` is meant to reduce the overhead of SOAP calls for external clients. Communication within Dynamics CRM (`Plugin` to `IOrganisationService`) doesn't have this overhead. I would recommend at least testing whether the performance is better with `ExecuteMultipleRequest` than without. Without, your code will be much simpler to read and maintain. `ExecuteMultipleRequest` will sequentially execute the inner `OrganisationRequest`'s, just like a foreach loop would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is immediately after you execute the `RetrieveMultiple` request

```
var entityRefs = result.Entities.Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_alterunitorderid"));
```

`new_alterunitorderid` is not an `EntityReference`. It is a primary key.

Instead try:

```
var entityRefs = result.Entities.Select(e => e.ToEntityReference());
```

You should also make use of your `tracing` object to include more output in your trace logs:

```
 tracing.Trace("Executing query");
 var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
 tracing.Trace("{0} results found. Converting to EntityReferences", result.Entities.Count);
 var entityRefs = result.Entities.Select(e => e.ToEntityReference());
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually batch jobs are asynchronous. Go in Settings > System Jobs. Search for your delete job. I never used this specific syntax but the logic seems ok.

Comment: But jasonscript has a point. new_alterunitorderid is not an entityreference, but a GUID. We need to pass an Entityreference List to the batch job, no?!

Comment: do you think something like this would work?
var entityGuids = result.Entities.Select(ent => ent.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_alterunitorderid"));
                    var entityRefs = entityGuids.Select(guid => new EntityReference("new_alterunitorder", guid));

Comment: Look at the update, the guids are all zeros!! LMAO!!